# Published vars can't be passed as Bindings ??, SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Can we pass a published property of ObservableObject class as @Binding to other view?

In the example below I want to pass the published property `filterSelection` to as @Binding to `FilterSelectionView`. The code compiles perfectly but after changing the menu selection from `FilterManuSelection` it does not update the UI. To tackle this issue I have done this workaround and it works perfectly. But I did't get the insight of this working.

Menu items are not updating when I pass `filterSelection` as @Binding.

[image]

But Once I pass the whole vm as ObserveObject then it works perfect.

[image]

```
    struct MealFilters {
        var dislike = ""
        var protein = ""
        var calories = ""
        var fat = ""
        var carbohydrates = ""
    }
    
    class MealRecommendationViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var filterSelection = MealFilters()
        
    }
    
    struct MealRecommendationView: View {
        
        @StateObject var vm = MealRecommendationViewModel()
        
        var body: some View {
            NavigationLink {
                 FilterSelectionView(vm: vm)
                //HideNavbarOf(view: FilterSelectionView(vm: $vm.filterSelection))
            } label: {
                Text("next")
                
            }
        }
        
    }
    
  
struct FilterSelectionView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    
    @ObservedObject var vm: MealRecommendationViewModel
//    @Binding var filterSelection: MealFilters
    
    var body: some View {
        loadView()
            
    }
}

// UIView extension
extension FilterSelectionView {
    
    func loadView() -> some View {
        VStack {
            
            VStack(spacing: 15) {
                FilterManuSelection(itemArray: ["on", "off"], placeholder: "Dislikes", selection: $vm.filterSelection.dislike)
                FilterManuSelection(itemArray: ["high", "low"], placeholder: "Protein", selection: $vm.filterSelection.protein)
                FilterManuSelection(itemArray: ["high", "low"], placeholder: "Calories", selection: $vm.filterSelection.calories)
                FilterManuSelection(itemArray: ["high", "low"], placeholder: "Fat", selection: $vm.filterSelection.fat)
                FilterManuSelection(itemArray: ["high", "low"], placeholder: "Carbohydrates", selection: $vm.filterSelection.carbohydrates)
            }.padding()
                .padding(.top, 10)
            
            Spacer()
            
        }
    }
    
}

struct FilterManuSelection: View {
    var itemArray = [String]()
    var placeholder: String
    @Binding var selection: String
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        HStack {
            Text(placeholder)
                .font(Font.custom(Nunito.Bold.rawValue, size: 20))
                .foregroundColor(Color(ColorName.appGray.rawValue))
            
            Spacer()
            Menu {
                ForEach(itemArray, id: \.self){ item in
                    Button(item) {
                            selection = item
                    }
                }
            } label: {
                    Text(selection)
            }
        }
       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior.

Keep in mind that `Binding` *doesn't* trigger a view update, it rather depends on its source of truth (any dynamic property such as a `State` or a `Published` property of an observed object for example) to trigger an update higher in the hierarchy.

So, in order for `FilterSelectionView` to be re-calculated one of its dependencies has to be changed and that is `vm` in your case (which will emit an `objectWillChange` when a published property is changed and trigger the view update).